# How do I calculate sums of consecutive numbers fulfilling a condition?

Tags: r

Consider the following data:

```
dataset <- c(0.5, 1.2, 1.5, 2.1, 2.0, 0.8, 1.4, 0, 2.4, 2.9, 2.9, 2.7, 1.4, -0.8, -0.4, -0.2)
```

How do I sum consecutive entries that are greater than 1?

```
1.2+1.5+2.1+2.0
1.4
2.4+2.9+2.9+2.7+1.4
```

(This question was [closed on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/308368/1352).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option with `cumsum`

```
i1 <- dataset <1
tapply(dataset[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1], FUN = sum)
#   1    2    3 
# 6.8  1.4 12.3
```

Comment: That's a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Extract a run length encoding for those entries that fulfill your criterion of being >1:

```
foo <- rle(dataset>1)
```

Now we need to label the different runs. We label runs of values <=1 as "0" and all those >1 by increasing integers:

```
foo$values <- as.numeric(foo$values)
foo$values[foo$values>0] <- 1:sum(foo$values[foo$values>0])
```

We now backtransform this to get the correct labels. Look at `index` to understand what is happening:

```
index <- inverse.rle(foo)
cbind(dataset,index)
```

We finally sum values by the different index values (and disregard those where the index is 0, because this sums the entries that are <=1):

```
by(dataset,index,sum)[-1]
```

Output:

```
> cbind(dataset,index)
      dataset index
 [1,]     0.5     0
 [2,]     1.2     1
 [3,]     1.5     1
 [4,]     2.1     1
 [5,]     2.0     1
 [6,]     0.8     0
 [7,]     1.4     2
 [8,]     0.0     0
 [9,]     2.4     3
[10,]     2.9     3
[11,]     2.9     3
[12,]     2.7     3
[13,]     1.4     3
[14,]    -0.8     0
[15,]    -0.4     0
[16,]    -0.2     0

> by(dataset,index,sum)[-1]
index
   1    2    3 
 6.8  1.4 12.3
```